# Converting observational-data indicator into a panel format per id (dplyr)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data based on reddit posts where each row represents a single reddit post, along with the username and whether a the month_year at which the post was written.
I also a binary variable, "collective action," that is coded 1 if a post contains a collective action call and 0 otherwise. And another variable "directed_to_whom" that predicts to whom is the post directed at (e.g. different branches of government).
However, I am trying to convert such measures into a panel-format where they are measured at the username-level, rather than per post.

I have a variable "id" that uniquely identifies each username, and for the "collective action," indicator I am interested in computing the proportion of posts written by username, Eric Cartman, that include mentions of collective action. For example, if Eric Cartman wrote 7 posts on reddit but only 5 of which were labelled as containing collective action, then Cartman would have a collective action proportion of 0.71= 5 collective action posts/ 7 total posts.
Similarly, if Cartman only mentions Congress in 4 out of 7 posts, then the proportion for Congress for username, Cartman, would be 0.571= 4 mentions of Congress/ 7 total posts.

Here is a data example:

```
dput(df[1:10,c(1,4,7,8,14)]) # Print data example with specific columns
```

output:

```
structure(list(id = c(213L, 365L, 411L, 192L, 154L, 443L, 453L, 
462L, 213L, 213L), username = c("Cartman", "Cartman", 
"Cartman", "Kyle profleski", "Kyle profleski", 
"Cartman", "Kyle profleski Kyle profleski", "Kyle profleski", 
"Cartman", "Cartman"), collective_action = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1), directed_to_whom = c("Congress", 
"Congress", "Senate", "Congress", "Congress", "president", 
"president", "Senate", "Congress", "Senate"), month_year = structure(c(2011.41666666667, 
2011.41666666667, 2011.41666666667, 2011.41666666667, 2011.41666666667, 
2011.41666666667, 2011.41666666667, 2011.41666666667, 2011.41666666667, 
2011.41666666667), class = "yearmon")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), groups = structure(list(
    uusername = c("Cartman", "Cartman", 
"Cartman", "Kyle profleski", "Kyle profleski", 
"Cartman", "Kyle profleski Kyle profleski", "Kyle profleski", 
"Cartman", "Cartman"), .rows = structure(list(
        5L, 4L, c(1L, 9L, 10L), 2L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -8L), .drop = TRUE))
```

My expected output is as follows where the
"direc_to_Congress__prop" measures the proportion of mentions directed at a given (i.e. Senate, Congress, etc) for each username. For instance, creating a column that strictly measures the mentions of Congress within all posts written by Cartman on reddit.

```
id.    username        collec_action_prop   direc_to_Congress__prop
521.   Cartman            0.71                        0.57
501.   Mr.Mackey            0.4                       .32
499    Kyle profleski       0.3                       0.09
```

Comment: can you show your expected output

Comment: Thanks for the question, see my updated post, hope it clarifies it further.

Comment: In your input data, I didn't find the `username` column.  Is the update based on the input data

Comment: @nesta1992 Please double check your `dput` output - it looks like this was not copied exactly here.

Comment: @akrun thanks, I have edited my post with a data example but only changed the usernames for privacy reasons.

Comment: @Ben Thanks for support, I have fixed the post now and only changed usernames for privacy. –

Comment: @nesta1992 Thanks - to get the `collec_action_prop` column, you can try the following `df %>% ungroup %>% group_by(username) %>% summarise(prop = sum(collective_action) / n())`...the `ungroup` is included, since your data is already grouped (by uusername with 2 u's)...after grouping, you can `sum` the `collective_action` and divide by `n()` which is the total number of rows for a given user (and rows = posts). The other column may require further explanation - it helps if the example data and the expected output "match" (anticipated values, and consistent variables)...hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks, the solution worked perfectly for all the binary variables. In regards to the "directed_to_whom" variable, I have added more details to the post which hopefully clarify the expected output.

Comment: @nesta1992 Try something like `summarise(prop = sum(directed_to_whom == "Congress") / n())` for proportion directed to Congress...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the advice by @Ben, here is the solution for both variables:

#Here I am computing the proportion of posts written by username, Eric Cartman, that include mentions of collective action.

```
df%>% ungroup %>% group_by(username) %>% 
  summarise(collective_action_prop = sum(collective_action) / n())
```

#Here I am measuring the proportion of mentions directed at a given in the "directed to whom" indicator, for posts written by a specific username

```
df%>% ungroup %>% group_by(username) %>% summarise(prop_Congress = sum(directed_to_whom == "Congress") / n())
```